# Macro for copying a specific Row of formulas into newly created rows

Tags: vba, excel

I recently posted a question, and unfortunately did not get very far with any answers. I have re-worked my macro to mirror a similar scenario I found elsewhere. The problem is I am now getting stuck at the very end.

Purpose of the macro:
1. Beneath the selected cell, I need to insert x new rows = entered months -1

1. In the first inserted row, I need a set of relative formulas that can be found in the Actual Row 2 of the current worksheet (basically copy and paste row 2 into the first row created)
2. In the subsequent inserted rows, I need a set of relative formulas that can be found in the Actual Row 3 of the current worksheet

As is, the macro does what I want, except I don't know how to paste row 3 in all subsequent rows. I'm assuming I need some conditional statement?

As mentioned in my last post, I am trying to teach myself VBA, so any help would be appreciated!!

```
Sub InsertMonthsAndFillFormulas(Optional vRows As Long = 0)
Dim x As Long
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select  'So you do not have to preselect entire row
If vRows = 0 Then
vRows = Application.InputBox(prompt:= _
  "Enter the total number of months in the program", Title:="Add Months", _
  Default:=1, Type:=1) 'Default for 1 row, type 1 is number
If vRows = False Then Exit Sub
End If

Dim sht As Worksheet, shts() As String, i As Long
ReDim shts(1 To Worksheets.Application.ActiveWorkbook. _
   Windows(1).SelectedSheets.Count)
i = 0
For Each sht In _
   Application.ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
Sheets(sht.Name).Select
i = i + 1
shts(i) = sht.Name

x = Sheets(sht.Name).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'lastcell fixup

Selection.Resize(rowsize:=2).Rows(2).EntireRow. _
 Resize(rowsize:=vRows - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Rows(2).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Selection.Offset(1).Resize( _
     rowsize:=1)
Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Selection.Offset(2).Resize( _
     rowsize:=1)
On Error Resume Next
Next sht
Worksheets(shts).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: A few questions: **1:** Why do you subtract 1 from vRows? What if the user keeps the default `Inputbox` value (1)? Currently your code would throw an error when trying to insert 0 (1-1=0) rows. **2:** Are you really attempting to loop through each selected sheet? That seems cumbersome for the user to have to select a cell on each sheet before running the procedure. **3:** What is `x` for? Is it a vestige of previous code?

Comment: Hi, so 1: I subtract 1 from vRows, because the question for the user is how many total months (I need the row that was selected to be the first of those months and then add the additional months data in the subsequent rows (i.e. if I say there are 6 months total, I only need 5 additional rows)) I don't know that logically "0" would ever be entered in this scenario. 2: I am not attempting to loop through each selected sheet - as mentioned before, I am trying to piece together a macro from other examples I have seen, and to be honest, do not fully know alternative code that may be shorter. Thx!

Comment: also - the x can be eliminated. it was used in a previous code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on your comments, the below code should meet your needs. But first, a few things to note.

- I've added several comments to help you understand what is happening in the code.
- Based on your comment regarding `vRows`, the code will now terminate if the user keeps the default input box value ("1"). The logic is that if the value is only one, then no rows need to be added. *Notice that I subtract 1 from the `Inputbox` value.*
- The code assumes you have headers or at least filled cells in row one. I use row one to find the last used column.
- If there's any chance that the wrong sheet can be active when this code is executed, uncomment line 16 of my code. (Obviously you'd need to change the code to reflect your sheet's name.
- Finally, this code assumes that the upper-left corner of your dataset is in `A1`.

---

**Tested on Sample Dataset**

```
Sub InsertMonthsAndFillFormulas(Optional vRows As Long = 0)

Dim lastCol As Long
Dim r As Range

'Ask user for number of months.
'If the user keeps the default value (1), exit sub.
If vRows = 0 Then
    vRows = Application.InputBox(prompt:= _
        "Enter the total number of months in the program", Title:="Add Months", _
        Default:=1, Type:=1) - 1
    If vRows = 0 Then Exit Sub
End If

'Uncomment this line if you are concerned with which sheet needs to be active.
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Select

With ActiveSheet
    'Set the range to work with as the cell below the active cell.
    Set r = ActiveCell.Offset(1)
    'Find the last used column. (Assumes row one contains headers)
    'Commented this out to hard-code the last column.
    'lastCol = .Rows("1:1").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    'Insert the new rows.
    r.EntireRow.Resize(vRows).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    'r needs to be reset since the new rows pushed it down.
    'This time we set r to be the first blank row that will be filled with formulas.
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1).Row, 1), _
             .Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1).Row, "H")) '<~~ Replaced lastCol with "H"

    '**Add formulas to the new rows.**
    'Adds row two formulas to the first blank row.
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, "H")).Copy r
    'Adds row three formulas to the rest of the blank rows.
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(3, "H")).Copy r.Offset(1).Resize(vRows - 1)
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Edit**

The variable `lastCol` is what defines the right most column to copy formulas from. This variable is set using column headers in row 1. I prefer using variables like this to make the code more robust (i.e. you can add a column to your dataset without breaking the macro), however, for this to work you need headers above every used column (or at least cells that contain values).

If you aren't concerned with adding more columns in the furture, you can hard-code the last column into the code (see my revisions).

Comment: Thank you a million! This helps very much and I appreciate your comments - I really wanted to understand fully what is going on. I did have one question. Although the macro works great, for whatever reason, it is not copying in the formulas for columns F-H. Any idea why that would be? Thanks again!

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Also, if this solution solved your issue, please consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer. :)